# IIS 8 on WS2012 shows .svc as content

Tags: wcf, iis, windows-server-2012

I have a C# WCF web service that I setup on WS2008R2 and it works fine.  I go into IIS and right-click JobService.svc, it opens up a browser and puts in a URL:

```
http://1.2.3.4/WebServices_DEV/JobService.svc
```

and the service shows.  Absolutely fantastic!

However, I have a WS2012 server and I try to do the same.
If I open up IIS and right click on JobService.svc, it opens a browser and puts in the URL correctly.
However, it shows:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WebService.JobService" CodeBehind="JobService.svc.cs" %>
```

Now my web.config shows like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
      <security> 
         <requestFiltering> 
            <requestLimits> 
               <headerLimits> 
                  <add header="Content-type" sizeLimit="100000" /> 
               </headerLimits> 
            </requestLimits> 
         </requestFiltering> 
      </security>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" /> 
  </system.webServer>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" initializeData="wcf-traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>

</configuration>
```

I don't know whether it's that I am relying on not specifying end points or bindings so I add them in:

```
<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="JobService" />
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="JobService" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

But it has no effect.

What I am I doing wrong please.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem now... orz

Answer (score 1):

It seems that IIS is missing handler mappings or Http Activation for WCF Services is disabled. Here is instruction how to fix it: [IIS 8 missing handlers](http://geekswithblogs.net/manjunath.k/archive/2013/12/08/hosting-wcf-service-on-iis8.aspx)

Following link can also help: [IIS Hosted Service Fails](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752252%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for that.  The HTTP Activation has been enabled and the handler mappings are there.  In fact there are more handler mappings on our 2012 server than out 2008R2 server.  Issue is very baffling!

Comment: 1) Try to re-register asp for iis:  aspnet_regiis –i –enable
2) "%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\ServiceModelReg.exe" -r
3) restart PC

Very often it does help

Comment: You can also try to remove feature "HTTP-Activation", restart. After that enable this feature, restart and check. Such kind of issues are usually very stupid, and constant attempting to do something helps :)

Comment: Thanks.  I can't do 1) on WS2012 as it gives this error message: This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.  Administr
ators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Win
dows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.e
xe command line tool.

Comment: Tried 2) and 3) - that went smoothly, but no change.  I'd have thought WS2012 would be mature and simple to set up - so wrong!

Comment: Also, I can add roles and features, but they are disabled afterwards so I can't switch them off to try and reinstall them.

Comment: Sorry, that I don't have strong answer, but the situation is very strange. Try to run Visual Studio Command Promt, and execute commands: DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:WCF-HTTP-Activation and
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:WCF-HTTP-Activation45 and restart PC after that

Comment: Thanks - no worries.  I'll look into it further.  I found out how to remove features.  Trying a few things as I removed HTTP Activation but then when I went to add it again, it was already there.  I might need to remove the entire IIS etc.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a solution

1. First make sure you install the necessary feature about wcf in the windows feature.

You can check all about IIS, and all about .Net Framework 3.5, 4.5

[image]

2. and maybe tou should add the MIME type:

> mimeMap fileExtension=".svc" mimeType="application/octet-stream"

3. add Service.svc to your default document

[image]

and run the site, I Success run the service.svc

[image]